# C++ std::map items in descending order of keys

Tags: c++, sorting, stdmap

How cal I use std::map container with key value in descending order.

As an example, if insert the following items:

```
[2 , 5]
[1 , 34]
[3 , 67]
```

They will be ordered in the map like:

```
position 0: [1, 34]
position 1: [2, 5]
position 2: [3, 67]
```

I can iterate through the map reversely, but suppose the next time I am inserting [-1 , 60]. Will it be placed at the first position?

Comment: Specifying where your objects will go kind of defeats the purpose of a map. You'd might as well use an array if that's the functionality you want.

Comment: Think of it, a map just hashes your items and throws them into a "random" location, so that you can access them again in O(1) time without worrying where they are located. If you can to store them in a specific location, you can just binary search them into an array, or sort the elements and insert them one by one.

Comment: @AlejandroLucena No, that's `std::unordered_map`. The usual `std::map` class **is sorted.**

Answer (score 72):

Use a custom comparator when the default order doesn't do it for you.
You pass it as the third template parameter ( that's normally defaulted to `std::less<KeyType>` ).
In your case, you can use `std::greater`:

```
std::map<int, int, std::greater<int> > m;
```

Example code:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main() {
  std::map<int, int, std::greater<int>> m { {-1, 77}, {0, 42}, {1, 84} };
  for (const auto& p : m)
    std::cout << '[' << p.first << ',' << p.second << "]\n";
}
```

Resulting output:

```
[1,84]
[0,77]
[-1,42]
```

Comment: can you please provide an example.. how can i sort it in reverse order... thank you.

Comment: @user2422669 this IS the example, just replace your map with one like this.

Comment: @user2422669 It is recommended to review this: [The STL (Primer)](http://www.amazon.com/The-STL-Primer-Graham-Glass/dp/0134549767).  Granted its publication date is 1995.  However, it will help understand that a `map` is always sorted, has the usual performance characteristics of a binary search tree (e.g. may continue to be a red-black tree deep in the map implementation), and can be sorted low to high or high to low as jrok has shown.  If the key is user defined, then it will be necessary to understand that the equality (`==`) and less than (`<`)operators have to be implemented.

Comment: Should add `#include<functional>`

Answer (score -1):

`std::map` is already sorted, so you only need to traverse the map using a `reverse_iterator`.

A map, however, is not an array. There's no such thing as "the n-th position" in a map. (`std::map` is most commonly implemented using some sort of binary search tree.) If you **absolutely, inevitably** need to specify order manually, then use a `std::vector<std::pair>`.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it misses the point. OP said that iterating in reverse is not an option. Also, it's perfectly fine to have a map sorted from greater to lower if that's a requirement.

Comment: Why one would suggest `reverse_iterator` here ? :S

Comment: @P0W Because `iterator` goes in the wrong direction, in first place?

Comment: @jrok arguably (that's your personal opinion at best).

Comment: @user3447428 OP said _"I want to insert..."_ not transverse